# Format thousand to Ks in R

Tags: r

How to format numbers like `465456.6789` to beautiful `465,4K` in R? Other examples 13567.566 to 13,5K 3567.5 to 3,5K and so on. In general I want something like

```
roundup_to <- function(x, to = 10, up = FALSE){
  if(up) round(.Machine$double.eps^0.5 + x/to)*to else round(x/to)*to
}

roundup_to(c((74453.867574737)), to = 100)
```

to become `74,5K`

Comment: shouldn't 465456.67 be 465,5??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also have a look at function `scales::label_number_si` which rounds the number.

```
a <- c(465456.6789, 3567.5, 1465458.12)
scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(a)

#[1] "465.5K" "3.6K"   "1.5M"
```

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
a <- c(465456.6789, 13567.566, 3567.5)
sprintf("%sK", format(round(a/1000, 1), dec=","))
[1] "465,5K" " 13,6K" "  3,6K"
```

Answer (score 1):

`scales::label_number_si()` from @ronak-shah s answer got deprecated in [scales 1.2.0](https://github.com/r-lib/scales/blob/main/NEWS.md#scales-120). Now you can do:

```r
a = c(465456.6789, 3567.5, 1465458.12)
scales::label_number(scale_cut = scales::cut_short_scale())(a)
```