# Formatting numbers with functions

Tags: r

I am trying to format the numbers in a dataframe using functions. Because there are many columns that needs to be formatted so i am trying to avoid it by creating functions.

```
##this is a dataframe
asdf <- data.frame(a = c(2133242,2421), b = c(4323,543532654))
```

```
##Function to format numbers
## df is a dataframe and column_name is column names
format_numbers <- function (df, column_name){
  df["column_name"] <- ifelse(nchar(df["column_name"]) <= 5, paste(format(round(df["column_name"] / 1e3, 1), trim = TRUE), "K"),
         paste(format(round(df["column_name"] / 1e6, 1), trim = TRUE), "M"))
  return(df)
}
```

Expected out put

```
asdf$a <- format_numbers(asdf, a)
asdf
        a         b
1     2.1M      4323
2     2.4K 543532654
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to ask a question and clarify the issue. (; Next. There is no need to re-invent the wheel, e.g. the `scales` package offers convenience functions  to format numbers, incl. e.g. `label_number_si`. Finally, inside your function remove the quotes around column_name and instead put quotes around the column name when calling the function format_numbers(asdf, a), don't return a data.frame, ....

Comment: `scales::label_number_si(accuracy = 0.1)(asdf$a)` ? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67680668/format-thousand-to-ks-in-r/67681515?noredirect=1